# Add/edit node auto share to social networks

Tags: nodes, rules

Is there any way to add an option to share to social networks selecting with checkboxes and with predefined messages using token that a new node has been added or than an old one has been edited?

I had an idea about rules, and the Social Share module but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [Janrain module](http://drupal.org/project/rpx) for getting similar functionality. It allows you to integrate social networking logins, set up buttons for social sharing and a lot of other stuff. Its actually pretty easy to set up the module

Some other modules include - [Socialmedia](http://drupal.org/project/socialmedia), [social login](http://drupal.org/project/sociallogin) If you are just looking for sharing - [Sharethis](http://drupal.org/project/sharethis)

Comment: Thanks Jayaram, but none of those modules allow you to set a rule to send a predefined message to some selected social networks after adding/editing a node, they just put a button to manual share a content.